# How do I flatten a folder structure and rename a file in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, cp

I'm attempting to flatten a folder structure containing code coverage reports across multiple functions into one folder. It will then be uploaded to a code analysis tool.

My input file structure looks like this:

```
artifacts/a/coverage-reports/coverage-a.xml
artifacts/b/coverage-reports/coverage-b.xml
```

My desired file structure is as follows:

```
coverage-reports/coverage-a.xml
coverage-reports/coverage-b.xml
```

I've tried this command which I think is *nearly* there, but I can't get adjust the final filename and remove the folder name:

```
find ./artifacts -name coverage*.xml -type f -exec bash -c 'file=${1#./}; echo cp "$file" ./coverage-reports/"${file//\//_}"' _ '{}' \;
```

The output is e.g.:

```
cp artifacts/a/coverage-reports/coverage-a.xml ./coverage-reports/artifacts_a_coverage-reports_coverage-a.xml
```

Is there a way I can adjust my shell command so that the destination file is `coverage-a.xml` and does not contain the full path?

Comment: `mkdir coverage-reports; mv artifacts/*/coverage-reports/* coverage-reports`?

Comment: Yep! Classic case of overthinking the problem. I'd been fixed on the above solution for nearly a day as well! Thanks.